# Modifying a variable from another class c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have to call the variable "rotSpeed" in my case. To the class difficulty, and change it accordingly. how do i call it?

The variable is in another class.

```
public float rotSpeed = 90f;
```

This is the variable

I need to call it to this code:

```
public class Difficulty : MonoBehaviour {

public float multiplyerx1 = .25f;
public float multiplyery1 = .4f;
public float multiplyerx2 = .25f;
public float multiplyery2 = .4f;
public Texture BackgroundTexture;


void OnGUI(){

    GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), BackgroundTexture);
    //Hard
    if (GUI.Button( new Rect(Screen.width * multiplyerx1, Screen.height * multiplyery1, Screen.width * .5f, Screen.height * .1f), "Hard")){
        //Put in change of rotspeed
        Application.LoadLevel("GameScene");
    }
    //Easy
    if (GUI.Button( new Rect(Screen.width * multiplyerx2, Screen.height * multiplyery2, Screen.width * .5f, Screen.height * .1f), "Easy")){
        //Put in change of rotspeed
        Application.LoadLevel("GameScene");
    }

}
```

Comment: this variable value will change any time any where?

Comment: try to declare this variable as private as get and set their value using getter and setters.

Comment: No this just controls how fast the enemies rotate their ships. So for easy it would be 60f, and for hard it would stay the same at 90f.

Comment: it means this variable value will change upon level selected.

Comment: Please learn some basic programming, Down voted for the lack of basic programming aptitude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make this field static as shown below :-

```
public static float rotSpeed = 90f;
```

and the class which is having this field should be static but not necessary and the you can fetch as shown below :-

```
ClassName.rotSpeed;
```

and if your field might vary in future then use properties as shown below :-

```
 private static float rotSpeed;
 public static float RotSpeed
   { 
        get { return rotSpeed; }
        set { rotSpeed = value; }

   }
```

and call as shown below :-

```
 ClassName.RotSpeed;
```

Comment: Static is never the best option, since the impact is class wide. Change anywhere will change value for all the other access. Try and use the instance variable. also never allow direct variable access, as suggested it should be always via a property